# Нужна ли запятая при однородных членах (условие: зависимые слова)?

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

Собирай скорее вещи, возьми брата, двух сестёр(,) и ступай за нами.
Ставится ли здесь запятая при таком условии: каждое однородное сказуемое имеет зависимые слова?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собирай скорее вещи, возьми брата, двух сестёр  и ступай за нами.

Пояснение

Несколько сказуемых могут рассматриваться как **однородные члены**, или такое предложение может считаться **сложносочиненным,** состоящим из односоставных предложений.

При решении этого вопроса учитываются различные факторы (иногда и р**аспространенность сказуемого)**, но в первую очередь смотрят **на форму глаголов:** в случае однородных сказуемых она должна быть **одинаковой** (тогда можно применять все правила для однородных членов).

Форма  касается наклонения глаголов. Так как в данном случае используется только повелительное наклонение, то сказуемые можно считать однородными.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Оглянитесь вокруг, и увидите столько нового и интересного (Газ.) — сложносочиненное предложение (**глагольные формы разных наклонений не выступают в роли однородных членов простого предложения**);

Другие примеры: Оденься потеплее,  и пойдем гулять. Выезжай завтра, и утром будешь на месте.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Почему разный вид глаголов (при этом другие категории совпадают) мешает их считать однородными сказуемыми? А если сказуемые совсем по-разному морфологически выражены: Она добра и любит читать книги. И здесь, кажется, запятая не нужна: Возьми себя в руки и делай, что говорят.

Comment: 1) Речь идет только об односоставных предложениях . 2) Возможно, вид глагола не влияет на решение и вы правы (Возьми себя в руки и делай, что говорят). Но наклонение точно влияет. Я исправлю ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая между однородными сказуемыми, соединенными союзом *и*, не ставится:

> Собирай скорее вещи, возьми брата, двух сестёр и ступай за нами.

Зависимые слова при сказуемых здесь неважны.

***Дополнение.*** Непонятен источник утверждений Jasmin о необходимой одинаковости видовых форм глаголов для их рассмотрения в качестве однородных членов. Пример, который верно привела Юлия, наводит на мысли о его некорректности: «Возьми *(сов. в.)* себя в руки и делай *(несов. в.)*, что говорят». Ср. также пример из НКРЯ, где сказуемые являются однородными, несмотря на разные видовые формы: «Я только с января начну *(сов. в.)* работать учителем и оооооочень боюсь *(несов. в.)*!» [коллективный. Форум: Были вы в стране преподаваемого языка? (2008-2011)]

В действительности, согласно одному из возможных взглядов, иногда важно *соотнесение с одним и тем же реальным временем*: «Он не *ел*, не *пил*, *лежал* неподвижно и *молчал*» (А. П. Чехов). Подробнее см. «Энциклопедия "Русский язык" под ред. Ю. Н. Каралова».

В любом случае запятая в указанном месте стоять не должна, так как союз *и* соединяет члены предложения, относящиеся к одному и тому же подлежащему (которое материально не выражено; «действующему лицу», если угодно).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70512/discussion-on-answer-by-aer--------).